# how to convert a part of array from int to float and set the value to another two arrays

Tags: c++

EDITED:I was trying and searching, but didn't find how to convert only the part when (j==3) to float, because i need the evaluation(grade or idk the exactly word) to be from 2 to 6 - it can be 3,5... so i need float. OK, check my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  unsigned int m[25][4], a[25][4], b[25][4];
  int i,j,n,k=0,p=0,g=0,t=0;
  do
  {
    cout<<"Enter number of students: ";cin>>n;
  }
  while(!(n>0 && n<=25));

  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    cout<<"Student N:"<<i+1<<"\n";
    for(j=0;j<4;j++)
      if(j==0)
      {
        do
        {
          cout<<"Fak nomer: ";cin>>m[i][j];
        }
        while(!(m[i][j]>=10000000 && m[i][j]<100000000));
      }
      else if(j==1)
      {
        do
        {
          cout<<"Enter Speciallity - 52 for E, 61 for AIUT"<<endl;
          cout<<"Code: ";cin>>m[i][j];
        }
        while(!(m[i][j]==52 || m[i][j]==61));   
      }
      else if(j==2)
      {
        do
        {
          cout<<"Group: ";cin>>m[i][j];
        }
        while(!(m[i][j]==1 || m[i][j]==2 || m[i][j]==3 || m[i][j]==4));
      }
      else
      {
        //float f=m[i][j];(i tried to replace all m[i][j] with f but..)
        do
        {
          cout<<"Avg. evaluation: ";cin>>m[i][j];
        }
        while(!(m[i][j]>=2 && m[i][j]<=6));
        //m[i][j]=f; 
      }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        cout<<setprecision(8)<<m[i][j]<<"\t";
      cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl; 
  }
```

Let's say we will make the whole array float, so i need to set the information based on two new arrays as it says:

```
if(m[i][1]==52)
   a[k][p]=m[i][j]
else if(m[i][1]==61)
   b[g][t]=m[i][j]
```

Actually i need to show them based on the group code if 52 to show the array with only 52... and if 61 to show only array with 61, somekind of sorting them... i tried some ways but i get that: "-9.2559631e+061" and i think as i said that i need unsigned array to work that... EDITED!

Comment: please fix your formatting (tabs/spaces etc.) it's bad enough trying to real a wall of code without explanation, but to try reading when it's badly formatted... hmm..

Comment: btw. you have to have an array of `float/double` - you can't mix and have a `float` in the middle of an array of `int`...

Comment: I think it is fixed enough ... maybe 2 or 3 places have missing lines .. dont make it a big deal...

Comment: float and double arrays can't be unsigned ...

Comment: Come on guys ... can you help me :|

Answer (score 0):

You can't. An array have all its entries of the same type.

There are a couple of ways to work around it though. The first is to make the whole array of type `float`. The other is to use something like the [Boost Any class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/any.html).

Comment: The problem is that I think i need unsigned array, because after that i need to fix them in two new arrays by the Speciallity: if(m[i][1]==52) then m[i][j]=a[k][p]; else if (m[i][1]==61) then m[i][j]=b[g][t]... and if it is not unsigned i get those numbers 34******** and -48******* ...

Comment: plus that the Number of student must be int number without point... in case array is float typing 12345678,5 is true (actually it is not it must be just 12345678), on other hand in 2nd "for" i need to show the array ... so that number 12345678 is a little high and the program works only with setprecision(8) and for avg evaluation i get    a lot of digits after the point ... i need only 1 or 2 ... that wont work with setprecision(8)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an array indexed off an arbitrary number to store different data items like that.  All you will do is give everyone a headache.

```
struct Student
{
    unsigned int fak;
    unsigned int speciality;
    unsigned int group;
    float grade;
}

Student students[25];
students[20].group = 1.7f;
```

while on the subject, please also stop using magic numbers (if the number 25 appears twice it should be a constant).

```
const int studentCount = 25;
Student students[studentCount];
```

There are other things too, but please start writing code with everything named instead of asking us, people you work with, or your future self next week, to try to figure out what j==3 represents...